# facebook javascript api get user email

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, email

I am trying to fetch facebook user email for my app. But when i query the email address is returned as null.
Forums suggest that the user should grant the email permission to your app. How to make user grant that permission or ask him what fields will he give access to the application.
I am able to get name but not email from the code below.

```
 FB.api(
    {
      method: 'fql.query',
      query: 'SELECT name, email FROM user WHERE uid='+FB.getSession().uid
    },
    function(response) {
          alert(response[0].name);

    }
  );
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

its prettry simple my dear just take permission at the time of login.

```
<fb:login-button perms="email" autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>
```

and take other permissions in perms with comma seperated values. I hope it will help

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much Awais. Exactly what i was looking for. Also thank you Javier for editing the text.

Comment: If you use the HTML5 syntax the attribute is `data-perms`